# Formatting a double within an interpolation

Tags: c#, formatting, double, string-interpolation

I have an interpolation where I need to format the variable to 2 places. The variable here is 'difference'

```
double difference = moneyLeft - trip;
Console.WriteLine($"Not enough money! {difference} needed.") ;
```

I have tried putting `{0:f2}` but doesn't seem to work. Currently it gives me a number like `418.2`, where I need it to be `418.20`. How can I fix it?

Comment: As you note below, you can include a format specifier inside the `{}` of an interpolated string. If `F2` doesn't work, I'm pretty sure `0.00` will

Comment: `{0:f2}` inside string interpolation is going to give `0.00`, always.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
double res = moneyLeft - trip;
string difference = String.Format("{0:0.00}", res); // say difference: 418.2
Console.WriteLine($"Not enough money! {difference} needed."); // Output: 418.20
```

Comment: Somehow fixed it like this: 
Console.WriteLine($"Not enough money! {difference:f2} lv needed.")

Comment: I'm on a phone, but it doesn't look like your code will compile. You recycle the variable name `difference`, but with two types

Comment: I have already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of the token syntax (`{ }`), the "before the colon", and the "after the colon".

When you're inside an interpolated string, the "before the colon" part is treated as code. That means if you use a variable name, it evaluates the value stored in that variable. If you give it a numeric literal, such as `0`, it uses the value `0`.

```
var input = 3.21;
string a = $"{input}"; // 3.21
string b = $"{0}"; // 0
```

`0` In this case *doesn't* mean the "first positional argument after the template", such as is used in `string.Format`.

You already figured out that you should use `f2` after the colon to get two decimal spots, but remember you can't use `0` before the colon, or else the value you'll be formatting is *literally* the number zero.

```
var input = 3.21267674;

// your first attempt
string a = $"{input}"; // 3.21267674

// your second attempt
string b = $"{0:f2}"; // 0.00

// the correct way
string c = $"{input:f2}"; // 3.21
```